# how can find all input elements value at same time in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, select, element, forms

My question is how can I find all input elements and search in the value of them?
I want to search all input elements that have the same name, find if the value of inputs is empty and alert something like this:

```
var emptyCheck = "";
function emptyOrNot() {
    if ($('[id="empty"]').val() == "") {
        emptyCheck = "empty";
    }
    else {
        emptyCheck = "filled";
    }
}
```

This code only finds the first input element in the form and can't find all of them. And the result will be wrong.

Comment: **1.** ID **should** be _unique_. **2.** `$('[name="empty"]')` will select multiple elements so you need to iterate over them using `each`.

Comment: $('[id="empty"]' you are using id. ID is always and must be unique use class

Comment: Use class like said before then use filter jq method: `if($('.empty').filter(function(){return !this.value.trim();}).length){ alert('At least one .empty element has no value!'); }`. One other option is to use `required` attribute: [form validation support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use $.each to check them all. Are you making your own form validation? :)

Ok here is how your code can be:

```
function emptyOrNot() {
    var emptyCheck = 0;
    $('input').each(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            emptyCheck++;
        }
   })
   if(emptyCheck == 0){
        return true;

   }else{
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Should an input with only white spaces validate? What about duplicate IDs? And anyway, here `element` isn't a jq object, use `$(element).val()` or better `element.value`

Comment: I just updated his code. So maybe he wants user to pass the form with spaces :) And you are right with the selectors. Corrected it with $(this) now it should do.

Comment: best, just elemnt had problem that you corrected that, thank you